# How to add a computer to domain and rename it with prompts and concatenates

Tags: powershell

I am building a script to speed up our rename and join process for a lot of imaged machines.  The goal is to have it prompt twice, once to get the asset tag (`$NewestName`) and again for domain credentials (`$c`).  The script goal is to concat the device prefix (shown as "ORG-LOC-") to `$NewestName` then concat the domain name to the credentials, so all I have to enter in the prompt is the domain username and password and NOT the absurdly long domain name.

These are Win10Pro workstations imaged using the 1809 build, joining a domain running in 2008R2.

```
$Assetname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the new asset name (W or L, followed by the 4 numbers in the asset tag)'
$c = Get-Credential
Add-Computer -ComputerName $Env:Computername -DomainName absurdly.long.domain.name.but.nothing.can.change.us -NewName "ORG-LOC-"+$Newestname -Credential "absurdly.long.domain.name.but.nothing.can.change.us\"+$c -Restart
```

I expect it to join the PC to the domain passing the modified credentials, then to rename the PC.

What I get is rejections on a few different variants of the script failing to adjust the name of the device and/or failing to concat the credentials or the new device name.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a typo in the post or not but `Env:Computer` needs to be `$env:Computer`. Also, `-Credential $c` should be enough for that parameter since `$c` will already contain the domain if you supplied it. So there's no need to do any appending of the domain name to `-Credential`.

Comment: @adminofthings Yeah, I am trying to avoid having to type all the extra if i can avoid it.  Lazy, but saves time.  It's very long.
If I am trying to do that, should I do the concat outside of the script and have it assign to a different variable?
You are right though, I had tried $Env:computername after this version, so that was a typo, made that change above.

Comment: You can precode the username by doing `Get-Credential -UserName "domain\" -Message "Append Username To Domain Name"`.

Comment: Still leaves me with the appended $NewestName, but I could do that outside as well:

`$Assetname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the new asset name (W or L, followed by the 4 numbers in the asset tag)'  
$NewestName = "ORG-LOC-"+$Assetname  
$c = Get-Credential -UserName "absurdly.long.domain.name.but.nothing.can.change.us\" -Message "Append Username To Domain Name"  
Add-Computer -ComputerName Env:Computername -DomainName absurdly.long.domain.name.but.nothing.can.change.us -NewName $Newestname -Credential $c -Restart`

Comment: And today I've determined that I simply cannot make the markdown work right in comments...